# How to list PDF page sizes in the command line

Tags: c#, ghostscript

In the Ghostscript documentation I did not found arguments to query the paper sizes of a PDF document.

I read about a pdf_info.ps file in the lib subdirectory.

I tried this code:

```
private const string RutaAGhostscript = @"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64c.exe";

...

Process pTamaños = new Process();
pTamaños.StartInfo.FileName = RutaAGhostscript;
pTamaños.StartInfo.Arguments = " -dNODISPLAY -q -sFile=\"" + RutaSeleccionada + "\" -DumpMediaSizes \"C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.52\\lib\\pdf_info.ps\"";
pTamaños.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pTamaños.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pTamaños.Start();
EscribirArchivo(pTamaños.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(), RutaResultadoTxt2);
pTamaños.WaitForExit();
```

I got this output in the result file:

```
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--
Operand stack:
   (C:\\Users\\claudio.bogado\\QGMI\\Ruben De Jes\303\272s Martinez - 2020-05 Certificado 16\\Tramo 3\\Certificado 16 Tramo 3.pdf)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:739/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:15/128(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
Current file position is 11770
```

Using the xPDF tools I tryed `pdfinfo -box` and some files with different page sizes only shows the first page.

Am I imputing wrong the file name?

UPDATE:

I tried using GetShortPathName of kernel32 to get rid of the spaces. The only difference in the error output was the name of the file that now is `C:\\Users\\CLAUDI~1.BOG\\QGMI\\RUBEND~1\\TRAMO3~1\\CERTIF~1.PDF`

Also tried changing the backslash for the slash and the difference is the error message now shows `C:/Users/CLAUDI~1.BOG/QGMI/RUBEND~1/TRAMO3~1/CERTIF~1.PDF`

Greetings from Paraguay.

Claudio Bogado Pompa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of Ghostscript default to SAFER mode by default, which prevents PostScript programs (like pdf_info.ps) from accessing files in the file system.

In general Ghostscript will try and infer from the command line when files should be permitted (such as the input filename, in the case above pdf_info.ps) but it can't know that -sFile= should be permitted, because that part of the command simply ends up in the PostScript interpreter.

So to use pdf_info.ps you will either have to set `-dNOSAFER` or add `--permit-file-read=` to your command line. `-dNOSAFER` turns off all protection so you may not want to do that, --permit-file-read allows the PostScript program to **read** the specified directory only. I'd recommend you do that.

I'd also suggest you experiment from the command line using the usual Ghostscript executable and only move to your application when you have it correct.

If you are planning to distribute this application, please have a look at the license file.